# Custom div inside elements don't retain properties

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, shadow-dom

So I've this code:

```js
const div = (tag) => {
  const ptag = document.querySelector(tag);
  const shadow = ptag.attachShadow({
     mode: 'closed'
  });
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.textContent = ptag.textContent;
  shadow.appendChild(div);
}
div('foo-bar')
```

```html
<foo-bar>
  <h1>Hi</h1>
</foo-bar>
```

I expected that the 'Hi' will appear in a usual, h1 tag like style, but here it does not. What would likely be the cause.

Fixes appreciated. Thanks in advance to co-helpers. Would be grateful for the making of [custags.js](https://obnoxiousnerd.github.io/custags.js).

Comment: i'll se the "Hi".. what's the problem?

Comment: h1 tag is not part of text context. No HTML tag is part of text content.

Comment: You are appending the child `div` to the `foo-bar` element not the `h1`

Comment: need hi to look like h1 text

Comment: @ObnoxiousNerd so is your question about styling shadow dom? See: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About `div.textContent` you're using, this will only fetch the content string and not whole HTML.

Quoting MDN

> The `textContent` property of the Node interface represents the **text** content of the node and its descendants.
>
> `Element.innerHTML` returns HTML, as its name indicates. Sometimes people use `innerHTML` to retrieve or write text inside an element, but `textContent` has better performance because its value is not parsed as HTML. Moreover, using textContent can prevent XSS attacks.

More about [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Differences_from_innerHTML).

It's better to use `innerHTML` in this case since you want to preserve `h1` from `foo-bar` here.

```js
const div = (tag) => {
const ptag = document.querySelector(tag);
  const shadow = ptag.attachShadow({
      mode: 'closed'
    });
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = ptag.innerHTML;
  shadow.appendChild(div);
}
div('foo-bar')
```

```html
<foo-bar>
<h1>Hi</h1>
</foo-bar>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, @Saharsh . In the evening, I too thought that innerHTML will work but I haven't got spare time to try. thanks for helping me in the development of custags.js

Comment: Gotta change everything to innerHTML for all elems. Lot of work